# Apply lead function on the first value

Tags: sql, sql-server, lead

So I used the lead function and it works great for leading the values of rows 2 and 3 as you can see below

[image]

Here is the code to generate that table in sql.

```
drop table timetable;

create table timetable(
names varchar(50),
timestart integer
);

insert into timetable values ('NAV',1);
insert into timetable values ('Jim',2);
insert into timetable values ('MIC',3);

select names
,timestart
, Lead(timestart) Over (order by timestart) as endtime
from timetable;
```

However I want to write a code that automatically creates a row above with no name and no timestart but with a endtime of 1, since that is the first row's timestart value. Below I have envisioned of what I want it to look like.

[image]

Comment: "Above" what? You are not sorting the rows.

Comment: Correct the rows are not sorted, what I am trying to do is lead every single value not just the vales below row 1. Meaning in a regular lead function 2nd rows's value (2) would be attached to the row above (the 1st row)'s last column, which is correct. However I also want the first row's value (1) to attach to a row above even if the row does not exist, hench write code that generates a row above and attach the value (1) to the last column. PS you are right, I do need to sort the rows, Thank You.

Comment: "...below row 1..." -- there's no such thing as row 1 or 2, or 3. Table rows do not have inherent order. You specify the order you prefer when retrieving them. In simple words, a database table **is not** an Excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are sorting by `timestart` you can do:

```
select * 
from (
  select 
    names, 
    timestart, 
    lead(timestart) over (order by timestart) as endtime
  from timetable
  union all
  select null, null, min(timestart) from timetable
) x
order by case when timestart is null then 0 else 1 end, timestart
```

Result:

```
names   timestart  endtime
------  ---------  -------
<null>     <null>        1
NAV             1        2
Jim             2        3
MIC             3   <null>
```

Comment: This does generate the correct graph, but I need it to select what ever value is contained in the first row's timestart column.

Comment: Fixed. However, your query still lacks ordering. You should make sure it includes an `ORDER BY` clause for all this logic to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

just add the `union all` to your query

```
select   names
        ,timestart
        ,Lead(timestart) Over (order by timestart) as endtime
from    timetable

union all

select  null
       ,null
       ,min(timestart) 
from    timetable

order by timestart
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good approach from a code duplication standpoint. I also take it that you probably don't know what that first `timestart` is going to be in advance. The way to use this is to drop your main query into the inner CTE. The new row is then added with a `timestart` value copied from that dataset.

```
with q as ( -- your real query here
    select names, timestart, endtime,
    from timetable ...
)
select null as names, null as timestart, min(timestart) as endtime from q
union all
select names, timestart, endtime from q
order by timestart;
```

This is very similar to The Impaler's solution but I think this might give you a small advantage if the logic is a lot more complicated than what you've written above.